# Validar imagen por JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero validar la imagen a través de JavaScript donde quiero validar el tipo de imagen (png, jpg, etc) y que el tamaño no sea mayor al establecido.

Por el momento he hecho esto:

```
document.querySelector("#imagen").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var file = this.files[0], image = new Image();
    if (/.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$/i.test(file.value))
    {
        alert('Comprueba la extensión de tus imagenes, recuerda que los formatos aceptados son .gif, .jpeg, .jpg y .png');
        document.getElementById("f1").focus();
        return false;
    }    
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    image.addEventListener("load", function(){
        console.log("Ancho: " + this.width + "px");
        console.log("Alto: " + this.height + "px");
    }, false);
}, false);
```

La validación quiero hacerla por `onchange`.

Comment: ¿Recibes algún error? ¿Cómo no funciona el código que tienes?

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben incluir un [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Échale un vistazo a ver si este `script` te puede ayudar, al pulsar un botón, eliges la imagen y si es válida se muestra en la página.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

     var extensionesValidas = ".png, .gif, .jpeg, .jpg";
     var pesoPermitido = 1024;

    // Cuando cambie #fichero
    $("#fichero").change(function () {

        $('#texto').text('');
 $('#img').attr('src', '');

 if(validarExtension(this)) {

            if(validarPeso(this)) {
        verImagen(this);
     }
 }  
    });

    // Validacion de extensiones permitidas

    function validarExtension(datos) {

 var ruta = datos.value;
 var extension = ruta.substring(ruta.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
 var extensionValida = extensionesValidas.indexOf(extension);

 if(extensionValida < 0) {
            $('#texto').text('La extensión no es válida Su fichero tiene de extensión: .'+ extension);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

   // Validacion de peso del fichero en kbs

    function validarPeso(datos) {

        if (datos.files && datos.files[0]) {

     var pesoFichero = datos.files[0].size/1024;

     if(pesoFichero > pesoPermitido) {
         $('#texto').text('El peso maximo permitido del fichero es: ' + pesoPermitido + ' KBs Su fichero tiene: '+ pesoFichero +' KBs');
         return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     }
 }
    }

  // Vista preliminar de la imagen.
  function verImagen(datos) {

      if (datos.files && datos.files[0]) {

          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
           $('#img').attr('src', e.target.result);
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(datos.files[0]);
       }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<input type='file' id="fichero" /><br/>    
<p id="texto"> </p><br/>    
<img id="img" src="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso, desde hace un tiempo he comenzado a considerar ciertas clases estratégicas para mi proyecto. Una de ellas es 
[jquery form-validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/index.html#file-validators_dimension) que incorpora validaciones javascript mediante jquery para múltiples usos en los formularios html/php que realizo.

Para tu requerimiento, en el caso de imágenes puedes validar el tipo de archivo de imagen, su tamaño en px (minimo y maximo), su encuadre (relación alto-ancho), entre otras tantas cosas.

En el caso de la validación de imágenes solo debes agregar las variables adicionales al campo input: `data-validation-allowing="jpg"` y `data-validation-dimension="min100"` para activarlo. Ver ejemplo:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
      <?php // campo IMAGEN NATURAL ?>
      <label for="img_natural" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Imagen Natural (N)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="file" id="img_natural" name="img_natural" accept="image/jpeg" data-validation-allowing="jpg" data-validation-error-msg="Elija una imagen con formato JPG." data-validation="required" />
        <p class="help-block">formato .JPG (requerido)</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <?php // campo IMAGEN MINIATURA ?>
      <label for="img_miniatura" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Imagen Miniatura (M)</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="file" id="img_miniatura" name="img_miniatura" accept="image/jpeg" data-validation-allowing="jpg" data-validation-error-msg="Elija una imagen con formato JPG." data-validation="required" />
        <p class="help-block">formato .JPG, tamaño 100 x 100 px</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button>Enviar</button>

  </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
  $.validate({
    modules: 'file'
  });
</script>
```

Para el caso de tamaños de archivos, puedes incluir las variables en el campo input:

```
data-validation="mime size" data-validation-allowing="jpg, png, gif" data-validation-max-size="2M
```

lo cual validará tamaño máximo 2MB y formato de los archivos a importar.

Es simple. Seguramente te preguntarás, ¿por qué incluir clases? En mi caso la respuesta fue que solo voy a sumar clases que resuelvan varios problemas a la vez. Si solo resuelve una validación o un rellenado, no vale la pena. Esta clase sí lo vale.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```js
function openImage() { //Esta función validaría una imágen
        
      var input = this;
      var file = input.files[0];
      var fileName = input.value;
      var maxSize = 1048576; //bytes
      var extensions = new RegExp(/.jpg|.jpeg|.png/i); //Extensiones válidas

      var error = {
          state: false,
          msg: ''
      };

      if (this.files && file) {

          for (var i = fileName.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {

              if (fileName[i] == '.') {

                  var ext = fileName.substring(fileName[i],fileName.length);

                  if (!extensions.test(ext)) {
                      error.state = true;
                      error.msg+= 'La extensión del archivo no es válida.<br>';
                  }

                  break;
              }

          }

          if (file.size > maxSize) {
              error.state = true;
              error.msg += 'La imágen no puede ocupar más de '+maxSize/1048576+' MB.';
          }

          if (error.state) {
              input.value = '';
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = error.msg;
              return;
          } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "El archivo es válido";
          }
         
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function(e) {
              document.getElementById("img").src = e.target.result;
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
  }
    document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change",openImage,false); //Añadimos un evento al input para que se dispare cuando el usuario seleccione otro archivo
```

```css
/* Un poquito de CSS  ;) */

* {
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type=file] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  background: #FF5555;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #FF5555;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition: ease 0.3s;
}

label:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #FF5555;
}

#result {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #666;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<label for="file">Elegir archivo</label>
  <input id="file" type="file">
  <br>
<div id="result">Esperando archivo...</div>
  <br>
<img id="img">
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda