# No funciona el segundo código para validar imágenes en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando validar el tipo y tamaño de imagen con javacript en dos campos `<input type="file">`.

Resulta que solo funciona uno, el otro no funciona y es una copia del primero.

Mi consulta es:

**¿Cómo puedo unificar el código para que me valide los dos `<input>`?**

Les dejo mi código (no funciona):

```
window.onload = function(){
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.onclick = function(){
var imagen = document.getElementById("fotofrente").files;
if(imagen.length == 0){
window.alert("La subida de imagen Foto Frente DNI es obligatoria");
return;
} else{
for(x = 0; x < imagen.length; x++) {
if (imagen[x].type != "image/png" && imagen[x].type != "image/jpg" && imagen[x].type != "image/jpeg" && imagen[x].type != "image/gif"){
window.alert("El archivo " + imagen[x].name + " no es una imagen");
return;
 }
if (imagen[x].size > 1024*1024*2){
window.alert("La imagen " + imagen[x].name + " para DNI FRENTE, supera el tamaño máximo permitido 2MB");
return;
}}}
document.formulario.submit();
return;
}}
```

Ese sería el primer `<input type="file">` que no me toma la validación.

Y el segundo sería (sí funciona):

```
window.onload = function(){
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.onclick = function(){
var imagen = document.getElementById("fotodorso").files;
if(imagen.length == 0){
window.alert("La subida de imagen Foto Dorso DNI es obligatoria");
return;
} else{
for(x = 0; x < imagen.length; x++) {
if (imagen[x].type != "image/png" && imagen[x].type != "image/jpg" && imagen[x].type != "image/jpeg" && imagen[x].type != "image/gif"){
window.alert("El archivo " + imagen[x].name + " no es una imagen");
return;
 }
if (imagen[x].size > 1024*1024*2){
window.alert("La imagen " + imagen[x].name + " para DNI FRENTE, supera el tamaño máximo permitido 2MB");
return;
}}}
document.formulario.submit();
return;
}}
```

Solo valida el segundo, el primero no.

Me gustaría unificarlo a ver si me valida los dos.

Comment: Porque no usas Jquery mejor? te dejo un ejemplo diñamico en otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96210/validar-imagen-por-javascript/123383

Comment: Avisa si te sirve :)

Comment: Estás cometiendo dos veces el mismo error al sobreescibir un atributo del DOM en vez de agregar un nuevo manipulador a la cola de eventos. Redactando respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema que estás sufriendo es hacer uso de las propiedades `onload` y `onclick` cuando modificas los atributos [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) y [`Elemento.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) dos veces.

Solo se mantiene la última asignación que hagas a dichas propiedades, la primera es sobreescrita con la segunda asignación y se pierde. Por ese motivo solo te funciona una y no las dos.

Existen varias soluciones a tu problema:

- Seguir haciendo uso de dichas propiedades pero iterar por ambos campos de envío de archivos para comprobar su validez.
- Registrar en la cola de eventos, mediante [`Elemento.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), ambas funciones.
- Registrar en la cola de eventos la función que itera los campos de envío de archivos.

Me voy a centrar en la tercera solución, por ser la más completa.

```js
/* Agregamos un manipulador para la carga de la página */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (evento) => {
    /* Agregamos un manipulador para el envío del formulario (y no la pulsación del botón) */
    formulario.addEventListener("submit", (evento) => {
        /* Buscamos los <input type="file"> */
        const imagenes = evento.target.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']");
        /* Iteramos por cada una de ellas para comprobar su validez */
        imagenes.forEach(campo => {
            if (campo.files.length === 0) {
                window.alert("La subida de imagen " + campo.dataset.descripcion + " es obligatoria");
                /* Evitamos el envío del formulario si éste no está bien */
                evento.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            /* Iteramos cada imagen del campo comprobando que tenga un tipo MIME adecuado */
            for (let i = 0; i < campo.files.length; i++) {
                if (
                    [
                        "image/png",
                        "image/jpg",
                        "image/jpeg",
                        "image/gif"
                    ].indexOf(campo.files[i].type) === -1
                ) {
                    window.alert("El archivo " + campo.files[i].name + " no es una imagen adecuada");
                    /* Evitamos el envío del formulario si éste no está bien */
                    evento.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                if (campo.files[i].size > 1024 * 1024 * 2) {
                    window.alert("La imagen " + campo.files[i].name + " (para " + campo.dataset.descripcion + "), supera el tamaño máximo permitido de 2 MiB");
                    /* Evitamos el envío del formulario si éste no está bien */
                    evento.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<form name="formulario" id="formulario">
  <input type="file" name="fotofrente" id="fotofrente"
      data-descripcion="Foto Frente DNI" /><br />
  <input type="file" name="fotodorso" id="fotodorso"
      data-descripcion="Foto Dorso DNI" /><br />
  <input type="submit" id="button" />
</form>
```

He hecho uso de [`Elemento.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) para acceder a la descripción de la foto a través del atributo `data-descripcion`. De ese modo centralizo en el HTML la descripción de las imágenes y no en el código JavaScript.